# How to populate a pdf field with superscript registered trade mark symbol 

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for some time.

- I'm using CF9's cfpdf to populate pdf fields.
- One field is a "title" field and one particular title must be
  followed by a registered trade mark symbol.
- The registered trade mark symbol **must be superscript**.

Does anyone have any possible solutions?

Thanks so much for your time.

Code snippet:

```
<cfpdfform 
action="populate" 
source="#var.workFiles##var.ID#.pdf" 
destination="#var.workFiles##var.ID#.pdf" overwrite = "true">

<!--this is the value that could contain the registered trademark -->

<cfpdfformparam name="title" value="#trim(var.title)#">
```

Comment: Can you post your code and version (CF9?)

Comment: Coldfusion9.  It's a huge amount of code, but I'll post a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a shortcut, but try something like this:

```
<cfset symbol = charsetEncode(binaryDecode("c2ae", "hex"), "utf-8")>
...
<cfpdfformparam name="title" value="XYZ Corporation#symbol#">
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Leigh's answers, I was also having issues with character encoding, specifically the `£` sign. which was being shown as `A£`.

I resolved the issue the same way, by looking for the hexicecimal representation of the £ symbol at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ (`c2a3` for the £ sign) and using the `charsetEncode(binaryDecode("c2a3", "hex"), "utf-8")` part from Leigh's answer with the correct hex code.